# setting default value of check box tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to set the default value of a check box, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using rails' `check_box_tag` helper, and yes I've looked through the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) for the helper and I still can't figure it out. Here is the code:

```
- @org.departments.each do |dept|
  %tr
    %td= label_tag dept.name
    %td= check_box_tag(dept.name, dept.name, is_dept_admin?(dept, @org, u))
```

I've verified that `is_dept_admin?(...)` returns a boolean value. If I simply replace the `is_dept_admin?(...)` method with the value `true`, every check box appears checked, so I'm not sure what's causing this weird behavior.

Any suggestions would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
check_box_tag(dept.name, dept.name, is_dept_admin?(dept, @org, u) ? true : false)
```

Comment: is_dept_admin?(dept, @org, u) method return boolean or string value?

Comment: It returns a boolean. I checked and it either returns an instance of FalseClass or TrueClass

Comment: `!Department.where( conditions ).empty?

Comment: is_dept_admin?(dept, @org, u) method is in helper class?

Comment: It's in the DepartmentHelper module

Comment: What should be the html generate? Inspect element -> html

Comment: So I was trying to render the checkboxes in a bootstrap modal, and that caused everything to be weird. Once I removed the modal, the code worked fine.